# Java 8 - Generic Supplier

Tags: java-8, type-erasure

Today I tried to [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) a constructor in generic. Why is it incorrect?

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.Supplier;

class Foo<R extends Collection<Integer>> {
    Supplier<R> supplier = R::new;  // Compiler error!
}
```

Error text:

```
java: unexpected type
  required: class or array
  found:    type parameter R
```

Is it because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html)? Or maybe I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: Calling `new R();` would not work either...

Comment: Do you know what R is at the time this code runs? (Hint: The compiler does not.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At compile time, all you know about `R` is its bound; that it is a subtype of `Collection<Integer>`.  You don't know what class `R` corresponds to.  But you are trying to reference a constructor -- and to reference a constructor, you have to know exactly what class you're trying to construct.  All of the following would fail to work for the same reason: it is not known what R is, and you need to know what R is to call its constructor.

```
Supplier<R> supplier = R::new
Supplier<R> supplier = () -> new R();
R r = new R();
```

The same would be true even if R were declares as `<R extends ArrayList<String>>`.  In this case, you'd know that R extends `ArrayList<String>`, but you still don't know what class it is!

If you were trying to access a virtual member of `Collection<Integer>`, it would work:

```
ToIntFunction<R> sizer = R::size;
```

because, whatever `R` is, it must have a `size()` method.